# how to get hour and minutes from field in oracle . with To_char

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in table with datatype
`INTERACTION_TMST    DATE`

When i am writing a query like this

`select  TO_CHAR(INTERACTION_TMST, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from abc`

I am getting output

```
2017-03-16 11:17:03
2017-06-27 13:47:49
```

My question is how can i get the hour and minute from this and insert in to separate column . I want to extract hour and minute from this how to do that.

Comment: The EXTRACT function might do the trick https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm

Comment: Use TO_CHAR with the appropriate format mask : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212

Comment: if i am trying to do this `select extract(timezone_hour from TO_CHAR(INTERACTION_TMST, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) from abc` it is giving me the error   `invalid extract field for extract source`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, you can play with the format masks and test with a query like this one to see what comes out :

```
SELECT To_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') FROM dual;
```

So in your specific case :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(INTERACTION_TMST, 'HH24') hours,
       TO_CHAR(INTERACTION_TMST, 'MI')   minutes 
FROM abc
```

Comment: Thank you. My doubt is how do i separate hour and minute from that. with this i am getting the whole timestamp

Comment: Yes, and using 'HH24:MI' in the format mask yields only hour and minute.

Comment: No problem. Worth noting that your question have been downvoted, probably because you could have found the answer to that in a really quick Google search. This kind of question is not usually very well recieved. Have a nice day !